# Different ascii value between Safari and Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, encoding, safari, macos-big-sur

Using macOS with BigSur version 11.4.

A file name on my mac called: второй

If i copy and paste the file name to chrome console and print `"второй".charCodeAt(5)` - 1080

Is Safari: `"второй".charCodeAt(5)` - 1081

This causes some discrepancies in my app.

Is there a way to handle this so both browsers will act the same?

Comment: That's not an ASCII value. That's a UTF-16 code unit value. (Those are not the same thing, not least because UTF-16 code units are 16 bits.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) two ways to write that word in Unicode: `второй` (as in your question), which uses a `и` ([U+0438](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=0438)) followed by the combining character for the mark ([U+0306](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=0306)); and `второй`, which uses a single code point ([U+0439](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=0439)) that is the combination of those (`й`). The one using a separate letter and combining mark is in normalization form D ("canonical decomposed," in which separate code points with combining marks are used where possible), and the one using the combined code point is in normalization form C ("canonical composed," in which combined code points are used where possible).

So for whatever reason, on Safari your string (in form D) is getting normalized to form C, but not on Chrome.

To ensure you're dealing with the same sequence of code points, you can normalize the string using the [`normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) method (ES2015+). It defaults to NFC, but you can pass it `"NFD"` if you want NFD:

```js
const original = "второй";
console.log("original:", original.length, original.charCodeAt(5));
const nfc = original.normalize(); // Defaults to "NFC"
console.log("NFC:", nfc.length, nfc.charCodeAt(5));
const nfd = nfc.normalize("NFD");
console.log("NFD:", nfd.length, nfd.charCodeAt(5));
```

Note that `charCodeAt` works in UTF-16 code *units*, not code *points* ([post on my blog about the difference](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/01/26/what-is-a-string/)), although it happens that in your example all of the code points are represented by a single code unit. You can use [`codePointAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt) to look at code points instead, although (again) in this particular case it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: FWIW, I go into normalization forms and code points and code units, etc., in some depth in Chapter 10 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.